# iPhone Toolbar on top of a Scrollview to save UImage?

Tags: iphone

ive been looking at some tutorials on a toolbar they all are implemented through the navigation controller delegate. Is there a way i could use the toolbar without using the navigation controller?

right now i have a ViewController with a Scrollview in that scrollview i have images when the user uses a touch gesture then i want a toolbar to be viewable and usable to the user just like on the Photo App.

i want to know how i could use the toolbar and make it functional without going through the app delegate and staying on the current viewController.

Answer (score 0):

A toolbar can be created and positioned just like any other view. Don't confuse toolbars with tabbars.

Comment: How would I be able to add it on top of the scrollview 
insertSub view atIndex:2. ?

Comment: If you want it like the Photo app, you need to have the toolbar be a sibling of the scroll view so that it is always visible no matter how the scrollview scrolls.

Comment: sorry but would you do an example by code im not really understanding your solution.